# ssh: execute several commands

Tags: shell, ssh

When I am tryin to run multiple commands via ssh in server_remote, the third command returns the result of local server.
For example:

```
ssh remote_server "cd $LOGPATH ; ls -ltr logProgram1* | tail -1"
```

rediects to local $LOGPATH  and doesn't return results from remote_server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote to get $LOGPATH passed to the remote shell. Now it just expands $LOGPATH locally and sends it over.

```
ssh remote-server "cd \$LOGPATH ; ls ....."
```

might work better.

Just a word of caution. Your environment might not be what you expect it to be as your shell init script files are not necessarily processed similarly to your interactive login shell. Check the environment first to make sure your $LOGPATH is what it is supposed to be.

```
ssh remote-server env
```

would be helpful if you need to debug.

Comment: "cd $LOGPATH " works well, but "ls -ltr logProgram1*" or "ls -ltr logProgram1\\*"didn't find any file yet there are many files with that pattern